# What kinda bike is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Crime frame, no markings. I really need help here. Some say it's a Haro.

[image][image]

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Its a frame, which could be a bike if you added some more pieces.  Its literally just scrap metal as it stands.

Comment: Also people lie - its not a haro if there's no supporting decals, documentation, receipts, original paperwork or warranty information.     Someone's gone to the effort to strip it of cranks and the headset cups.

Comment: So u can't tell me what it is

Comment: BMX bikes pretty much all look the same, and theres so many frames that people misidentify deliberately that its practically impossible to tell what kind of frame it is, unless there's something unique about it and/or  one has a reliable history of that particular bike.

Comment: Stolen and stripped bike!

Comment: Is that a manufacturer decal on the down tube, or just another sticker?

Comment: After a little digging the decal on the downtube is also just a sticker, for Demolition BMX who makes components but not frames. I would say this will be filed in the unidentifiable pile.

Answer (score 2):

If I not wrong this frame is BMX bike frame. I have added a bike frame look like your one. If you need more information just ask me. Thanks!

[image]